# jhipster kubernetes command fails at the beginning with "No monolith found in ..."

Tags: kubernetes, jhipster

I just ran through the `JHipster` demo "Learn JHipster In 15 Minutes" and I'm now trying to deploy the result into kubernetes using [these instructions](https://www.jhipster.tech/kubernetes/). It's failing on the 2nd question.

```
$ jhipster kubernetes     
INFO! Using JHipster version installed globally
⎈ Welcome to the JHipster Kubernetes Generator ⎈
Files will be generated in folder: /Users/johnaron/git/JHipDemo/k8s
✔ Docker is installed
? Which *type* of application would you like to deploy? Monolithic application
? Enter the root directory where your applications are located (../) ../
>> No monolith found in /Users/johnaron/git/JHipDemo/
```

This is the listing of the parent directory

```
$ ll ..
total 4384
drwxr-xr-x    40 johnaron  staff     1280 Jun 22 16:08 .
drwxr-xr-x@   99 johnaron  staff     3168 Jun 22 16:13 ..
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff      853 Jun 15 18:26 .browserslistrc
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff      478 Jun 15 18:26 .editorconfig
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff       92 Jun 15 18:27 .eslintignore
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff     3041 Jun 15 18:26 .eslintrc.json
drwxr-xr-x    12 johnaron  staff      384 Jun 22 16:13 .git
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff     3413 Jun 15 18:26 .gitattributes
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff     2075 Jun 15 18:26 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x     7 johnaron  staff      224 Jun 15 18:41 .gradle
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff       53 Jun 15 18:26 .huskyrc
drwxr-xr-x     5 johnaron  staff      160 Jun 15 18:31 .jhipster
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff      113 Jun 15 18:26 .lintstagedrc.js
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff       69 Jun 15 18:26 .prettierignore
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff      251 Jun 15 18:26 .prettierrc
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff      143 Jun 15 18:26 .yo-rc-global.json
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff     1468 Jun 22 16:12 .yo-rc.json
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff     7404 Jun 15 18:26 README.md
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff     3210 Jun 15 18:26 angular.json
-rw-r--r--@    1 johnaron  staff      418 Jun 15 18:29 blog.jdl
drwxr-xr-x     8 johnaron  staff      256 Jun 15 18:44 build
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff    10204 Jun 15 18:26 build.gradle
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff      793 Jun 15 18:26 checkstyle.xml
drwxr-xr-x     9 johnaron  staff      288 Jun 15 18:26 gradle
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff     2424 Jun 15 18:26 gradle.properties
-rwxr-xr-x     1 johnaron  staff     5960 Jun 15 18:26 gradlew
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff     2842 Jun 15 18:26 gradlew.bat
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff     1448 Jun 15 18:26 jest.conf.js
drwxr-xr-x     2 johnaron  staff       64 Jun 22 16:08 k8s
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff      530 Jun 15 18:26 ngsw-config.json
drwxr-xr-x  1228 johnaron  staff    39296 Jun 15 18:33 node_modules
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff  2108706 Jun 15 18:33 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff     6672 Jun 15 18:33 package.json
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff      694 Jun 15 18:26 settings.gradle
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff     1538 Jun 15 18:26 sonar-project.properties
drwxr-xr-x     4 johnaron  staff      128 Jun 15 18:26 src
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff      151 Jun 15 18:26 tsconfig.app.json
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff      729 Jun 15 18:26 tsconfig.json
-rw-r--r--     1 johnaron  staff      285 Jun 15 18:26 tsconfig.spec.json
drwxr-xr-x     5 johnaron  staff      160 Jun 15 18:26 webpack
```

What is `jhipster` looking for?

John

Now I tried moving the k8s dir to the same level as the JHipDemo, but it was no help.

```
johnaron@JOHNARON-M-841U:k8s$ jhipster kubernetes     
INFO! Using JHipster version installed globally
⎈ Welcome to the JHipster Kubernetes Generator ⎈
Files will be generated in folder: /Users/johnaron/git/k8s
✔ Docker is installed
? Which *type* of application would you like to deploy? Monolithic application
? Enter the root directory where your applications are located (../) ../JHipDemo
>> No monolith found in /Users/johnaron/git/JHipDemo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to create it at the same level as your monolith. For example:

- JHipDemo
- k8s

Can you try this?

Comment: When prompted, use `../` for the application path. It should detect JHipDemo and display it as an option.

Comment: It didn't help, I updated my question above to show doing it that way.

Comment: OK pointing it to the *parent* of the JHipster project dir worked. Thanks!